# Saxon issue with Norwegian characters

Tags: xml, encoding, saxon

Using Saxon to process a xml file: http://meltwaternews.com/magenta/xml/html/18/2/rss/v2_406837.rss2.XML  which includes some Norwegian characters like Æ, Ø, Å.
xml encoding is utf-8

However, error occurs: illegal html character: decimal 152. (http://meltwater.vacau.com/s2.png)

But decimal 152 which is ~, can't be found in the original xml file.

and if I use windows-1252 to process this xml file with Saxon, I can actually see Æ, Ø, Å are miss-parsed as Ã˜ Ã¥ (u can see a decimal 152 here) (http://meltwater.vacau.com/s1.png).

Can some one suggest how to make it right?

Comment: Does the error identify the offset in the file where it thinks the bad character is?  Your link to http://meltwater.vacau.com/s2.png does not seem to work.

Comment: Your links to http://meltwater.vacau.com/*.png do not seem to work. Also, decimal 152 is not `~` (0x7F or 127 decimal) but a superscript tilde `˜` in windows-1252.

Comment: I ran your XML through an identity-template stylesheet in both Saxon 6.5.5 and Saxon 9.4.0.3 with no difficulties.  Is it possible the bad character is in the stylesheet and not the XML input?

Comment: try http://jackbu.x59.cn/img/s1.png and http://jackbu.x59.cn/img/s2.png.  And sorry I mistyped ~.  Yes, it's ˜. If u use saxon to parse Æ, it would be Ã˜.

Comment: I'm very suspicious of RSS feeds - encoding errors are very common. Also, the content at the cited URL is constantly changing - the fact that there was a miscoded character yesterday doesn't mean that it is still present today.

Answer (score 1):

Use character map.

```xslt
<xsl:character-map name="meltwater_fix">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#152;" string="˜"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

and then add to output element:

```
<xsl:output> or <xsl:result-document>
```

following attribute:

```
use-character-maps="meltwater_fix"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with the norwegian character 'Ø'. The problem is not saxon specific, the problem exists also in apache xalan. `Illegal HTML character: decimal 152`

I managed to get it working by making sure that both the XML and XSL documents was correctly encoded (some text editors may show the correct text but still save the document as UTF-8 or some other encoding). I saved all my test documents using vim `:write ++enc=ISO-8859-1` to make sure the documents were saved with the correct encoding.

I also had to specify the output encoding of the XSL-Transformer:

```java
String encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.getTransformer(xsltDocumentSource);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
```